# Jquery snippet does not executes in JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, dynamic-forms

I have a dynamic web project in eclipse. I have a JSP and a html file. 
In my JSP file , I include a html file that has jquery snippet inside script tag.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#in_school").change(function() {
            var in_school = $(this).val();
            $(".in_school_input").hide("fast", function() {
                $("#in_school_" + in_school).show("slow");
            });
        });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div>
            Are you in school? <select id="in_school">
                <option selected="selected">Please choose</option>
                <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="no">No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="in_school_yes" class="in_school_input" style="display: none;">
            What grade are you in? <input type="text" name="grade" />
        </div>
        <div id="in_school_no" class="in_school_input" style="display: none;">
            What year did you graduate? <input type="text" name="graduation_year" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

My **JSP** page is :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hello World - JSP tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@include  file="htmldata.html" %>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this program I only see the form but when I choose the dropdown, nothing happens . It does not prompts me the other questions based on dropdownvalue. Inshort I see that jquery part is never executed.

The expected output is [Expected_Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RDtVZ/).

Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong ?
Thanks !

Comment: Where are you including jquery library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your jsp code. 
1- You are have not included jQuery script in html.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

2- You have placed javascript before your html. Here is full code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div>
            Are you in school? <select id="in_school">
                <option selected="selected">Please choose</option>
                <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="no">No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="in_school_yes" class="in_school_input" style="display: none;">
            What grade are you in? <input type="text" name="grade" />
        </div>
        <div id="in_school_no" class="in_school_input" style="display: none;">
            What year did you graduate? <input type="text" name="graduation_year" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#in_school").change(function() {
            var in_school = $(this).val();
            $(".in_school_input").hide("fast", function() {
                $("#in_school_" + in_school).show("slow");
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Include jquery in your html before `<script>` that is using it:

Here's a link for cdn :

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`

You can chose to [download](http://jquery.com/download/) it and include from your own application path

Also, you need to wait until your html loads:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#in_school").change(function() {
            var in_school = $(this).val();
            $(".in_school_input").hide("fast", function() {
                $("#in_school_" + in_school).show("slow");
            });
        });
      });
    </script>
```